# Python list append different lists in the same scope for the same variable

Tags: list, arguments, pass-by-reference, python-3.5

Okay. I write an algorithm for show me all the permutations of a list of integers. But during the algorithm I got a problem to append a permuted list to my result list.

The code is the heap's algorithm. I got my finished permutation when `size == 1`. So a can append the permutated list `V` to my final list `res`. Here's the code:

The function for permutate the list

```py
def permutations(V, size):
    global res

    if size == 1:
        print(V)
        res.append(V)

    for i in range(0, size):
        permutations(V, size-1)

        if size % 2 == 1:
            V[size-1], V[0] = V[0], V[size-1]
        else:
            V[i], V[size-1] = V[size-1], V[i]

A = [1,2,3]
res = []
permutation(A, len(A))
print(res)
```

And this is the output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 2]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
res: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

The printed permutations of V are all correct. But the list V append to my `global res` are not change. They are being append right after the print and the list append is different.

If you change the lines like this:

```py
res.append(V)
  |
  |
  v      
D = [V[i] for i in range(len(V))]
res.append(D)
```

The results is correct on the final. Anyone can explain how can a printed list can be different from a appended list using the same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `res.append(V)` with `res.append(list(V))` simply fixes your issue.

All `V` you appended to the res are references to the same object. This can be observed by printing the id of each element in the list:

```
for i in res:
    print(id(i))
```